# CloudFoundry Instance. vmc error: "Denied: Operation not permitted"

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

I was deployed my own Cloud Foundry instance on top of vSphere with uaa settings:

```
uaa:
    catalina_opts: -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    jwt:
      signing_key: |
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        My key
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      verification_key: |
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        My key
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    cc:
      token_secret: aaabxaiC371JM
      client_secret: aaaF5DMNDZIfCb9A
    clients:
      dashboard:
        secret: aaauKyUCZF53kBKS
        scope: openid,dashboard.user
        authorities: uaa.admin,uaa.resource,tokens.read,scim.read,scim.write
        authorized-grant-types: client_credentials,authorization_code,refresh_token
    admin:
      client_secret: aaa5fER8evgEisjj
    login:
      client_secret: aaad2FyZS5jb20iL
    batch:
      username: aaaH2AKay2jAc
      password: aaaTiplI5Q83n
    scim:
      users:
      - b29|admin|openid,dashboard.user
```

I can login into my instance but all my commands (vmc push, vmc delete-user etc.) finished by this error:

```
FAILED
Denied: Operation not permitted
```

It's error of uaa configuration?
Some issue in cloud controller and uaa relationship?

Comment: Hard to tell without more logs to look at (cloud_controller first then UAA).  You *do* have to be very careful with the jwt key settings in the UAA properties because it's hard to create valid YAML with multiline content that stays valid when converted to a PEM, but as long as you keep the indentation (as you have in the sample above) that should work.

Comment: Briliant gues about jwt key settings. I removed this section and it works now. I can't investigate this error now but I think a problem that I'm using http protocol for uaa rather https. I will inform you about result soon.